# why I got the error: "Size exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE" when using spark+cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have 7 cassandra nodes (`5 nodes with 32 cores and 32G memory, and 4 nodes with 4 cores and 64G memory`), and deployed the spark workers on this cluster and spark's master was in the `8th node`. And I used [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) for them.  Now my cassandra has almost 1 billion records with 30 fields, I write the scala including the following snippet:

```
def startOneCache(): DataFrame = {
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.0.184")
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "username")
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "password")
  .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4G")
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "12G")
  .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb","64")

val sc = new SparkContext("spark://192.168.0.131:7077", "statistics", conf)
val cc = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)
val rdd: DataFrame = cc.sql("select user_id,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
,col7,col8 from user_center.users").limit(100000192)
val rdd_cache: DataFrame = rdd.cache()

rdd_cache.count()
return rdd_cache
}
```

In the spark's master I use `spark-submit` to run the above code,when executing the statement: `rdd_cache.count()`, I got a `ERROR` in the one worker node: `192.168.0.185`:

```
16/03/08 15:38:57 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 4 remote fetches in 221 ms
16/03/08 15:43:49 WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_6_0 in memory! (computed 4.6 GB so far)
16/03/08 15:43:49 INFO MemoryStore: Memory use = 61.9 KB (blocks) + 4.6 GB (scratch space shared across 1 tasks(s)) = 4.6 GB. Storage limit = 6.2 GB.
16/03/08 15:43:49 WARN CacheManager: Persisting partition rdd_6_0 to disk instead.
16/03/08 16:13:11 ERROR Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 4194304 bytes, TID = 24002
16/03/08 16:13:11 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 24002)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

I simply thought the final error `Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE` is caused by the warn: `16/03/08 15:43:49 WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_6_0 in memory! (computed 4.6 GB so far)` before it, but I don't know why, or whether I should set a larger than `.set("spark.executor.memory", "12G")` , what should I do for correcting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No Spark shuffle block can be greater than 2 GB.](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/top-5-mistakes-to-avoid-when-writing-apache-spark-applications/25?src=clipshare)

> Spark uses [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) as abstraction for storing blocks and its size is limited by [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) (2 billions).

Low number of partitions can lead to high shuffle block size. To solve this issue try to increase the number of partitions using [`rdd.repartition()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) or [`rdd.coalesce()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) or.

If this doesn't help, it means that at least one of your partitions is still too big and you may need to use some more sophisticated approach to make it smaller - for example use randomness to equalize distribution of RDD data between individual partitions.

Comment: While this is a correct answer some explanation going with would be useful.

Comment: `Rado Buransky`, thank you!  what should I do to get how many partitions are in the current rdd ? In my spark UI the total tasks are `23660`, which is the current number of partitions, if yes, how many partitions I should set for resolving this error?

Comment: @abelard2008 Try this: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/performance_optimization/how_many_partitions_does_an_rdd_have.html

Comment: `Rado Buransky`, thank you! From the link, I can get the number through   `rdd.toJavaRDD.partitions.size()` ( my rdd type is DataFrame, so I use `rdd.toJavaRDD), but what should I do to get how many partitions I should set for my case?

Comment: @abelard2008 I don't think you can find a general rule. You have to understand what is the nature of your data. In the slides you can find that a good rule of thumb is to have partitions about 128 MB in size. So probably you need to make an expert guess.

Comment: `Rado Buransky`, thank you very much for your patience and knowledge!